# Split Datatables columns every x columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am use the Javascript version of DataTables ([Link](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)) and I would like to split a big DataTable every x columns.

Any suggestions or a plugin?

Problem:

[image]

Instead of using x-srcolling I would like to be able to break the big datatable into 2-3-x smallers.

Comment: what do you mean with "split"?

Comment: I mean that I might have a table with 20-25 columns. That's too much information to be displayed in a single table and I would like to split this into 2 or 3 seperate `dataTables` with 5 columns each. That's also useful for printing purposes.

Comment: Given your example above, you could simply have one month displayed at a time and have a forward / back button for next / prev months, like the jQuery UI calendar. That shouldn't be too hard but I am not familiar with this plugin and don't have any of your code to play with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to have multiple tables,symply create different html tabbles and initialize them separately with different ids like in [this](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/multiple_tables.html) example.

Or you could show ecxtra data with a button like in this [example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/row_details.html)

Comment: But I need to have different tables per x columns. Can I somehow do that? Or I need to split them before passing them in datatables? THanks

Comment: @salamis You must have afull html table for each dataTable

Comment: Yes. In order to do that I will have to split the tables manually in HTML